# Access private key after personal.newAccount in web3.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, ethereum, web3py

I have created an Ethereum account using `web3.py` in python 3.6:

```
web3.personal.newAccount('password')
```

How do I access the private key for that account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an account on your node (which `w3.personal.newAccount()` does), the node [hosts the private key](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#local-vs-hosted-keys); direct access to it is not intended.

If you must have local access to the private key, you can either:

- Generate a new one with [`w3.eth.account.create(extra_entropy)`](http://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eth_account.html#eth_account.account.Account)
- [Extract the existing key from your node's keyfile](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#extract-private-key-from-geth-keyfile).

If the node is geth, extracting the key looks like:

```
with open('~/.ethereum/keystore/UTC--...4909639D2D17A3F753ce7d93fa0b9aB12E') as keyfile:
    encrypted_key = keyfile.read()
    private_key = w3.eth.account.decrypt(encrypted_key, 'correcthorsebatterystaple')
```

*Security tip -- Do not save the key or password anywhere, especially into a shared source file*

Comment: When i use this `web3.eth.account.create(extra_entropy)` , it doesn't create new account in my node

Comment: That's correct. But you can generate a geth-style keyfile that most nodes can import, with `w3.eth.account.encrypt()`. See http://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eth_account.html#eth_account.account.Account.encrypt for parameters and example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you **have been activated personal rpc of your geth**, to do this programatically **without hardcoding the keystore file directory path** in **python**, do the following:

```
from web3 import Web3
import eth_keys
from eth_account import account

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://127.0.0.1'))
address = '0x...'
password = 'password'

wallets_list = w3.geth.personal.list_wallets()
keyfile_path = (wallets_list[list(i['accounts'][0]['address'] for i in wallets_list).index(address)]['url']).replace("keystore://", "").replace("\\", "/")
keyfile = open(keyfile_path)
keyfile_contents = keyfile.read()
keyfile.close()
private_key = eth_keys.keys.PrivateKey(account.Account.decrypt(keyfile_contents, password))
public_key = private_key.public_key

private_key_str = str(private_key)
public_key_str = str(public_key)
```